# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have migrated my Magento site from shared to VPS, after complete migration it is showing some kind of error. Here it is.

> a:5:{i:0;s:250:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mojaric1_mage767.mgw0_log_visitor' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `mgw0_log_visitor` (`session_id`, `first_visit_at`, `last_visit_at`, `last_url_id`, `store_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";i:1;s:2645:"#0 /home/mojaric1/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

[image]

Comment: Check if mgw0_log_visitor is exist in DB after migration or not?

Comment: You should check too in the `app/etc/local.xml` if there is (or was in your old hosting) a node `<table_prefix>`.

Comment: Yes here is a node of <table_prefix> in <table_prefix>@JulienLoizelet

Comment: Yes there is no any table named mgw0_log_visitor in database, but i have manually imported database from my old server. Now its showing php fetal error. @aman

Comment: Check your dump file if having this table or not, might be somehow this table is missed.  Or you can create table manually in new server now.

Comment: I have imported backup from old server now its showing in my database but  now it is showing Fatal error: Call to undefined function iconv_substr() in /home/mojaric1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php on line 103  @aman

Comment: Have the other tables the prefix mgw0_ ? Have you tried to create manually this table (like 'aman' said)? I wonder that only this table shows the error.